# Cancel an AlertDialog when screen is rotated

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an AlertDialog.Builder displaying on an application. When I rotate the screen, I get "application has leaked window" error. How do I cancel the AlertDialog in the onPause() event? I don't see any method for Ad.cancel().

**Update**: code edited for working model.

```
   private AlertDialog inputDlg; 
   ...
   @Override
   protected void onPause ()
   {
     // close dialog if it's showing
     if (inputDlg != null)
        if (inputDlg.isShowing ())
          inputDlg.dismiss ();

      super.onPause ();
   }

   ...

   private void dlgUserPrompt (Context c)
   {
      // Set an EditText view to get user input 
      final EditText input = new EditText (c);

      AlertDialog.Builder Ab = new AlertDialog.Builder (this);
      Ab.setTitle("title");
      Ab.setMessage("I won't explode if you rotate this");
      Ab.setView(input);
      inputDlg  = Ab.show ();
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [dismiss](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#dismiss%28%29) method.

Comment: Actually, when using AlertDialog.Builder, you don't get a simple dismiss method. After reading Kurtis's reply, it looks like the solution is actually quite complex.

Comment: The show() method on AlertDialog.Builder returns an AlertDialog object that does indeed have a dismiss method. Unless you're doing something very computationally intensive in your view, you're better off just letting Android kill/restart your activity on configuration change rather than overriding this in your manifest as it is a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `onConfigurationChange()` hook to do this. This [document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges) will help explain to you more about what a configuration change is exactly and how to handle them.